# Create a mirror square number?

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

I am allowed to use the array `row(1: 4), column(A1:D1), MMULT, TRANSPOSE, MUNIT,, +-*/, mod,sqrt,.. , functions`

My question is: how to create symmetric matrix (matrix3-3,matrix4-4) like in image in both Excel and googlesheets?

[image]

I'm looking for a general method for this type of math!

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Hi @Dominique, I've split them up and down and put them together, but it seems to be quite long. I hope there is a faster method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((
 SPLIT(REPT(ROW(A1:A3)&" ", ROW(A1:A3)), " ")-TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A3))+1>0)*(LEN(
 SPLIT(REPT(ROW(A1:A3)&" ", ROW(A1:A3)), " ")-TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A3))+1)),
 SPLIT(REPT(ROW(A1:A3)&" ", ROW(A1:A3)), " ")-TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A3))+1, TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(REPT(ROW(A1:A3)&" ", ROW(A1:A3)), " ")-TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A3))+1)))
```

[image: 0]

for **4×4** grid use **A1:A4** instead of **A1:A3**

Comment: Hi,  I want the diagonal of this matrix equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks @player0. I tried it, works very well. I will see it as a solution but hopefully can be faster. I am using the matrix multiplication, divide method and using int(matrix) to evaluate these part matrices and then adding them together. however they are quite troublesome.